# Optimizing SQL Server Query (CTE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

This query takes forever to run. Does anybody have any good tips on how I can optimize it?

```
WITH CTE (Lockindate, Before5, After5) AS (SELECT nl.Lockindate, 
(CASE WHEN CAST(RIGHT(FirstLockActivity,8) AS time(1)) <= '17:00' THEN
'Before 5 PM' END) AS before5,
(CASE WHEN CAST(RIGHT(FirstLockActivity,8) AS time(1)) >= '17:00' THEN
'After 5 PM' END) AS after5
FROM netlock nl WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN rate rs WITH(NOLOCK)
ON nl.id=rs.id
WHERE nl.lockindate BETWEEN '2016-08-01' AND '2016-08-31')
SELECT lockindate, COUNT(After5), COUNT(Before5)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY lockindate
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes on those tables?

Comment: Just something to be aware of for the future, you have the value of where time = 17:00 in both parts of the case statement. You should make sure you know which one it should be included in.

Comment: Nothing immediately appears wrong with your code. First, look at the Actual Query Plan that is generated and see if it is breaking down into a FULL Table scan (think you need index on lockindate).  The NOLOCk suggests to me that blocking is occurring (probably from lock-escalation due to table scan) and this was the work around.  As you know NOLOCk can be dangerous because it will read from uncommitted transactions - which if they rollback will cause your query to error or... (dangerous part) return data that doesn't exist.

Comment: May I know the data type of `FirstLockActivity`, and the sample data?

Comment: @HLGEM thanks for that catch.

Comment: @ripvlan since i'm only an analyst and work on the reporting side for some reason I don't have permission to view the execution plan. The no locks is just so that I don't lock up any tables while running the query.

Comment: @Alex FirstLockActivity is a datetime. 

Sample (2012-10-18 18:28:30.437).

Comment: I should have mentioned that the netlock table is actually a view and is not  an indexed view since the data changes constantly.

Comment: Can anybody re-write the query to so it only uses derived tables (no temp, variable, or CTE)?

Comment: Permissions permissions.  Try this at top of script, place a GO after it:  SET STATISTICS IO ON   / GO.   While it won't give you the PLAN - it might give some insight into where execution is taking place.     BOL says that SHOWPLAN permission is NOT required for this command.  This will output the number of IO per table/worktable.    Documentation & Example usage...   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it won't speed up things all that much **IN THIS CASE** (*), the conversions from one datatype to another and then another again are 'not optimal'.

```
(CASE WHEN CAST(RIGHT(FirstLockActivity,8) AS time(1)) <= '17:00' THEN 'Before 5 PM' END) AS before5,
```

First of all you do an implicit conversion from a datetime [FirstLockActivity] to a string. The reason for this being that the Right() function expects a string, and hence the conversion. 
Doing implicit conversions can be dangerous. Depending on the configuration of your server (and even of your connection which by itself might be influenced by the regional settings of your operating system) this can result in surprising results, not all of which will have the expected last 8 characters!

FYI: have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 . As you can't explicitly pass the 'style' with CAST I've always suggested to people to rather use Convert(), ESPECIALLY when converting from datetimes to string, and vice versa.

After that you take the right-most 8 characters and then convert these into a time(1). I'm not sure why you want to use a time(1) over a time(0) since you're only interested in the hour part, but in the end it won't make much difference I guess.

Anyway, doing all these conversions takes CPU and thus time.

Assuming this thing isn't too dumbed down from what you really want to do, the target of the query is to return an indication on how many entries there were before and after 5 PM for each lockindate. As such, all you need to do is calculate the hour of each FirstLockActivy and decide from there.
=> `Hour(xx)` and `DatePart(hour, xx)` will both return the required information for a fraction of the CPU-cost of those conversions.
Also, you can easily get the before/after in one CASE construction.

```
  WITH CTE (LockinDate, Before5PM)
    AS (SELECT Lockindate, 
               (CASE WHEN Hour(FirstLockActivity) < 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Before5PM

          FROM netlock nl WITH (NOLOCK)
          JOIN rate rs WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON nl.id=rs.id
         WHERE nl.lockindate BETWEEN Convert(datetime, '2016-08-01', 105) AND Convert(datetime, '2016-08-31', 105))
  SELECT LockinDate,
         After5  = SUM(1 - Before5PM),
         Before5 = SUM(Before5PM)  
    FROM CTE
   GROUP BY LockinDate
```

Assuming the amount of (relevant) records in the tables is huge, then this will have some effect on the duration, but given the speed of modern processors it probably won't be shocking. Off course, when you're on a busy server and there isn't all that much (free) CPU going around, then the effect will be much more noticable.

That said, as for performance I'd suggest to check the indexes on the `netlock` and `rate table`. Ideally `netlock` has a clustered index (or PK) on the `id` field and a non-clustered index on `lockindate`. Additionally, the `rate` table has a clustered index on the `id` field with some additional other fields I'm not aware of. If the latter isn't the case, having a non-clustered index on the `id` field with the `FirstLockActivity` field in the included column would be great too.

If you want to have this query without the CTE, you can simply copy paste the CTE into a subquery/derived table like this:

```
 SELECT LockinDate,
        After5  = SUM(1 - Before5PM),
        Before5 = SUM(Before5PM)  
   FROM (SELECT Lockindate, 
                (CASE WHEN Hour(FirstLockActivity) < 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Before5PM

           FROM netlock nl WITH (NOLOCK)
           JOIN rate rs WITH (NOLOCK)
             ON nl.id=rs.id
          WHERE nl.lockindate BETWEEN Convert(datetime, '2016-08-01', 105) AND Convert(datetime, '2016-08-31', 105)) A
  GROUP BY LockinDate
```

Or, worked out a little more you'd get

```
 SELECT LockinDate,
        After5  = SUM(1 - (CASE WHEN Hour(FirstLockActivity) < 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)),
        Before5 = SUM(    (CASE WHEN Hour(FirstLockActivity) < 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
   FROM netlock nl WITH (NOLOCK)
   JOIN rate rs WITH (NOLOCK)
     ON nl.id=rs.id
  WHERE nl.lockindate BETWEEN Convert(datetime, '2016-08-01', 105) AND Convert(datetime, '2016-08-31', 105)) A
  GROUP BY LockinDate
```

PS: wrote all this in the browser, there might be some typo's and none the code is tested, prepare to have to fiddle around a bit to get it working =)

PS: if you can't get the query plan, you might still be able to use `SET STATISTICS TIME` to more easily compare one version of the query to another.

(*: In case you do this kind of conversions inside the `WHERE` clause or a `JOIN` clause, it will *confuse* the optimizer and the results could be devastating for the performance of your query)

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful and really optimized my initial query. Though, I don't understand the logic behind "After5 = SUM(1-Before5PM)

Comment: Well, you want the `COUNT()` in case the criterium matches. A bit like having COUNTIF() in excel. However, since we don't have COUNTIF in TSQL, we use SUM(x) and make sure that x is 1 (one) in case the criterium is met, and 0 (zero) when it isn't. In this case, we use `Before5PM' as a field and we know that it is `1` in case the record shows it happened before 5PM and `0` in case it happened after that. As a result, when we do `1 - Before5PM` the result is `0` in case Before5PM was `1`. And the result is `1` in case Before5PM was `0`, in other words, it reverses the criterium.

Comment: I see, I've never used this function before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a CTE:

```
SELECT nl.Lockindate, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(RIGHT(FirstLockActivity,8) AS time(1)) <= '17:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS before5,
   SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(RIGHT(FirstLockActivity,8) AS time(1)) > '17:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS after5
FROM netlock nl WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN rate rs WITH(NOLOCK)
ON nl.id=rs.id
WHERE nl.lockindate BETWEEN '2016-08-01' AND '2016-08-31'
GROUP BY nk.lockindate
```

But this might result in exactly the same plan. Then you need to check why it's slow (missing indexes on the join/group by columns?)

Comment: Hey can't use the sum operator in this case since it's varchar data

Comment: @NickV: The CASE returns a number, so you don't sum VarChars :)